# Thymeleaf: th:each error

Tags: for-loop, thymeleaf

I want to do this in thymeleaf template, but I got error

```
<tr th:each="user : ${userList}" th:id="${user.id}}">
    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.gender}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.level}"></td>
</tr>
```

error

```
Could not parse as expression: "${user.id}}"
```

Please tell me how to deal with this problem  :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `}` twice in the error line. Try this.

```
<tr th:each="user : ${userList}" th:id="${user.id}">
    <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.gender}"></td>
    <td th:text="${user.level}"></td>
</tr>
```